# Three.js imported model antialiasing

Tags: javascript, html, three.js

I import an OBJ model into a scene, but it is not antialiased and I can't figure out, how to make it smooth. And blender opens it smoothed.

Also built-in geometry (e.g. `new THREE.SphereGeometry(4, 20, 20);`) is smooth.

Renderer:

```
    var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({antialias: true, alpha: true});
```

Material:

```
    var modelMaterial = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
        color: 0xb9d5ff,
        ambient: 0xfff660,
        shininess: 100,
        wireframe: false,
        transparent: true,
        opacity: 0.8,
        side: THREE.DoubleSide,
        combine: THREE.MixOperation
    });
```

Import:

```
    var manager = new THREE.LoadingManager();
    manager.onProgress = function(item, loaded, total) {
        console.log(item, loaded, total);
    };
    var loader = new THREE.OBJLoader(manager);
    loader.load('BlondeElexis-nude.obj', function(object) {
        object.traverse(function(child) {
            if (child instanceof THREE.Mesh) {
                console.log(child);
                child.material = modelMaterial;
            }
        });
        object.position.y = 0;
        object.scale.x = 6;
        object.scale.y = 6;
        object.scale.z = 6;
        human = object;
        scene.add(human);
    });
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: where is the code for creating your THREE.WebGLRenderer?

Comment: updated the question.
`var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({antialias: true, alpha: true});`
In fact, any options has no effect on this

Comment: antialiasing is not the problem here, it is the smoothing groups of your mesh. OBJ should be able to handle this so check your obj exporter for this option to include smoothing groups. Using the ComputeVertexNormals() command will result in a completely smoothed object, which is maybe ok for organic objects but you should check the exporter and OBj importer. Maybe try another format if OBJ does not work out for you

Comment: @GuyGood thank you, I'll accent modelers on this. At the moment I'm just playing with sample models to make some drafts

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found:

```
child.geometry.computeVertexNormals();
```

Result is not the best, but better then nothing.

Comment: The comment by GuyGood is correct, You need to set smoothing groups on your model in your 3d program and make sure smoothing groups are included when you export.